# Why can't we access or re-assign a value to an OuterClass instance field from within InnerClass, outside its method/block?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am preparing for Java 11 certification and while revising Java concepts, I got trapped in one of the silly concept.
I know that `OuterClass`'s instance fields could be accessed from an `InnerClass` using `OuterClass.this`.
Please help me to understand why we cannot re-assign a value to `OuterClass`'s instance fields inside an `InnerClass` (outside a method or block).

```java
public class OuterClass {

    String outerInstanceField = "Outer instance field"; // Instance Field

    class InnerClass {
        OuterClass.this.outerInstanceField = "Inside Inner Class, now";
    }
}
```

Above code throws error:

[image]

However, this works perfectly fine if the re-assignment is done either in a block or in the `InnerClass` method.

```java
public class OuterClass {

    String outerInstanceField = "Outer instance field"; // Instance Field

    class InnerClass {
        {
            OuterClass.this.outerInstanceField = "Inside Inner Class, now";
            System.out.println(OuterClass.this.outerInstanceField);
        }
        
        void print(){
            OuterClass.this.outerInstanceField = "Inside Inner Class's method, now";
            System.out.println(OuterClass.this.outerInstanceField);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();  
        InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
        innerObject.print();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Nested Class class example

```java
class OuterClass {

    static String outerInstanceField = "Outer instance field";  // Static/Class Field

    static class InnerClass {
        
        OuterClass.outerInstanceField = "Inside nested Class, now"; // Compiler error
        
        static {
            OuterClass.outerInstanceField = "Inside nested Class's static block, now";  // works fine
            System.out.println(OuterClass.outerInstanceField);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686/6045800). I don't have much knowledge (these days...) in Java. This is why I didn't (couldn't) answer your question and most certainly didn't downvote it. I edited it as you didn't even put the Java tag so the people you need wouldn't be able to see your question. I see that since then you got 2 answers. You're welcome...

Comment: Thanks! @Tomerikoo and now I regret for pointing it out.
I am not very used to stackoverflow conducts. 
Thanks for your contribution. Keep up the good work.

Comment: No problem at all! A little tip (that could be related to the downvote) - try to avoid posting images as much as possible. Anything text-based should be formatted directly into the question. The error messages you posted could be posted as text instead of images. This helps search engines to find your question if someone searches the error message. An image is not searchable. If you're having a hard time formatting it, feel free to ping me and I'll help you edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but where you first have this assignment is a completely non-dynamic (for lack of better word and because I don't want to use the in this context ambiguous word 'static') area. There you would define things about the current scope, like which fields this class has or which methods.
That's why the assignment to `String outerInstanceField` works, as you are in the Scope of the `OuterClass` and are defining how it is defined.

What you are doing in the `Innerclass` is actually dynamic, i.e. something that would be executed. But you cannot even tell, when. Is it at the time of class loading? When some object is created? You have no information about that.
You also cannot put for example an if or a loop there, which basically is the same.

In this second snippet you could for example also try to add a `static` before the block. This will also not work, because it will be executed when the class is loaded and then you cannot even have an instance of OuterClass.

Edit, as response to your comment: It would be nice if you added a small example of what you mean, so I can be sure but if I understand correctly, the problem is the following: The InnerClass in your example is not static. This means, it will always belong to exactly one instance of OuterClass. This is, why OuterClass.this is unambiguous and works. On the other hand, there can be an arbitrary number of InnerClass-Objects for one OuterClass Instance, i.e. InnerClass.this can not be determined uniquely and therefore does not work.

Comment: Thanks! @Christian, for your response.
It even works if I assign `OuterClass.this.outerInstanceField` to some instance field of `InnerClass`. But, just opposite doesn't work.

Comment: @Vinit I added an edit section to my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Hey @Christian, apologies for the confusion.
I have added an example using nested class, to show what I meant, by "using static block".

Comment: @Vinit alright. This is what I tried to explain with this "non-dynamic area". What you are doing there is not failing, because you are assigning something to `OuterClass.outerInstanceField` but because you are doing something `active`, i.e. something that would be interpreted at runtime. This is not allowed outside of {}-blocks. The same you cannot put any kind of ifs or fors there.

Comment: If it helped you, you could accept the answer :)

Comment: I have accepted this answer, as it made me look around the grey area pointed out by @Chirtian.

Answer (score 0):

Considering below scenario:

```java
public class A{
    int x = 10;
}

class B extends A{
    x = 0;  
    int y = x;
}
```

If we execute above code, we receive compiler error:

[image]

We cannot have isolated expressions outside the scope of a constructor, a method, or an instance/static initialization block.

So, the questions narrows down to whether variable assignment is an expression or statement.

In The Java™ Tutorials, under topic [Expressions, Statements, and Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) it is mentioned that assignment and declaration are statements.
Also,

> Learning Java, by Patrick Niemeyer, Daniel Leuck

mentions,

> Technically, because variable assignments can be used as values for further assignments or operations (in somewhat questionable programming style), they can be considered to be both statements and expressions.

So, I am considering it as special case of expression.